# Magento2 Products List Page taking much time too load products

Tags: magento2, performance, product-listing

I have setup Magento 2.4.6-p2 Version in my local system
I enabled the profiler to see the loading time of the site and I found the below file is taking
too much time if I visit the list page the first time
[image]

and with second visit it is faster even without cache too . does anyone know its magento normal behaviour or something taking much time from database